# How do I deal with these error messages in Processing using the UnfoldingMaps library

Tags: image-processing, dictionary

The following Processing program (sketch in the jargon) displays a zoom-able world map. I copied it from [this site](http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/getting-started-in-processing.html). This is my first go at this library, and later I hope to develop a program to plot GPS position data on zoom-able and pannable maps.

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*;

UnfoldingMap map;

void setup() {
    size(800, 600);
    map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
    MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
}

void draw() {
    map.draw();
}
```

It initially displays a world map and gives this warning immediately:

```
Unfolding Map v0.9.6
No OpenGL renderer. Using Java2DMapDisplay.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
(de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.AbstractMapDisplay).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I am able to zoom in very nicely to a scale of about 1:50,000, but attempting to zoom closer brings up this long list of errors. I assume they depend in detail on which area I am looking at, but they are always pretty much the same.

```
Unfolding Map v0.9.6
No OpenGL renderer. Using Java2DMapDisplay.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
(de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.AbstractMapDisplay).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/18/130751/86722.png" is missing or   
inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch   
and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/18/130751/86723.png" is missing or   
inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch  
and is readable.
       .... (cut out about 30 similar warnings)
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/15/16320/10950.png" is missing or  
inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch  
and is readable.
```

So, my question is: please, what does this all mean, and can or should I do anything about it. There is a lot of postings about this on the net, but the suggestions are very confusing, and they all assume that you already have an insight into what is going on.

Comment: It looks like some map tile images for resolutions finer than 1:50,000 may not be available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfolding Map developer here.

The first two lines in the message panel give you some information about the version of Unfolding and the Processing renderer you are using. You can switch the renderer simply by specifying it in Processing's size method, e.g. `size(800, 600, P2D);` The next warnings notify you of an improperly set up log4j, a logging system. This should not happen since a couple of versions, so I wonder why you see this. (Can you name OS, Java and Processing versions?)

Regarding your main question: Yes, the default map tile provider (bw-mapnik) only provides zoom levels up to 18. You can switch to some other map providers which provide up to 19, but they are rarer. (see e.g. [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_servers) for some examples) Check our tutorial on how to [set or switch map tile providers](http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/mapprovider-and-tiles.html) and this [list of available Unfolding providers](http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/index.html?de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/providers/package-summary.html).

However, with the default map you should already be able to zoom to levels providing map resolutions up to 1:2000 (compare [OSM wiki on zoom levels and resolutions](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels)).
If you need resolutions higher than that (say 1:500) you have to create your own map provider. For instance, TileMill allows creating tiles up to zoom level 22, which might be sufficient for your needs. The exported map you then can use with Unfolding.